# "cmd.exe" exited with code 3 in Visual Studio 2017 when building a C++ app with a lot of "The system cannot find the path specified." int the output

Tags: c++, qt, cmd, build, visual-studio-2017

I am building my first C++ project, that I tried to debug, because of an issue. The project has not been build for the past 4/5 years, but the instructions were to run a bat file, which ran a "qmake -t vclib" for all directories in the project. This created a .vcproj file. Opening the file said

> "These projects are either not supported or need project behaviour
>   impacting to open this version of Visual Studio"

error message.
[picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aOKb.png)

After this, I pressed "OK" which created a .vcxproj file in the directory where the .vcproj was created. I also got this message [second error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAw68.png). From here I opened the .vcxproj file which should be the upgraded version of the project and I get again the second error. When I hit Build I get these errors: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKGOU.png)
and in the Output:

```
1>------ Up-To-Date check: Project: ccCore, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Project is not up-to-date: last build was unsuccessful.
1>------ Build started: Project: ccCore, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 18/06/2018 10:46:52.
1>Building with tools version "15.0".
1>Target _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform:
1>  Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_InvalidConfigurationError)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ).
1>  Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_InvalidConfigurationWarning)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ).
1>  Using "Message" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>  Task "Message"
1>    Configuration=Debug
1>  Done executing task "Message".
1>  Task "Message"
1>    Platform=Win32
1>  Done executing task "Message".
1>  Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(OutDir)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(OutDir)')) was evaluated as ('.\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('.\')).
1>  Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)')) was evaluated as ('obj\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('obj\')).
1>  Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(IntermediateOutputPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(IntermediateOutputPath)')) was evaluated as ('_obj\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('_obj\')).
1>Target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" skipped. Previously built successfully.
1>Target SetTelemetryEnvironmentVariables:
1>  Using "SetEnv" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common.dll".
1>  Task "SetEnv"
1>    VSTEL_SolutionSessionID={22C99F8C-EC4B-4478-B4C6-9F995893CCFD}
1>  Done executing task "SetEnv".
1>  Task "SetEnv"
1>    VSTEL_CurrentSolutionBuildID=470085203
1>  Done executing task "SetEnv".
1>  Task "SetEnv"
1>    VSTEL_ProjectID={0171C2BC-3F1A-43E1-B151-47FFAC18B480}
1>  Done executing task "SetEnv".
1>Target _PrepareForBuild:
1>  Task "CreateItem" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(CustomBuild.IncludeFileToTool)'!='') was evaluated as (''!='').
1>Target _PrepareForReferenceResolution:
1>  Task "Message" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(_REFERENCE_DEBUG)'=='true') was evaluated as (''=='true').
1>Target "ComputeCrtSDKReference" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(ClCompile)'!='' and '$(WindowsAppContainer)'=='true' and '$(UseCrtSDKReference)' != 'false') was evaluated as ...
1>    Generating precompiled header source file '..\..\falcon_precomp.h.cpp'
```

...

```
1>    MOC ..\include\ccFE\AppService.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccFE\PluginWidgetWebPage.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccFE\URLHandler.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccFE\YenkaWebPage.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccFE\YenkaWidget.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccModel\AutoLayoutBaseSet.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccModel\ComputedPropertyCallback.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccModel\ContentsTreeStore.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccModel\DocumentService.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccModel\EventRegistry.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccModel\Formatter.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccModel\LiveQuerySet.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccModel\NodeFilter.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccModel\OutputTransform.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccModel\OutputTransformManager.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccModel\PartAssociationHelper.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccModel\PartsTreeStore.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccModel\PhononMediaPlayer.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccModel\PixelDistanceConverter.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccModel\ReplacementSet.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccModel\SetValueCommand.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\ccModel\TreeStore.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\cc\AccurateTimer.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\cc\FeatureService.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\cc\HttpFileHandler.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\cc\JavaScriptBridge.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\cc\SettingsService.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\cc\Signaller.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ..\include\cc\WeakPointer.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC collision\CollisionSpaceImpl.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC commandManager\commandManager.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC licence\LicenceDownloader.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC licence\licenceService.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\action_impl.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\borderLayout.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\camera\cameraAnimations\CameraAnimation.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\canRotate3dCallback.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\control_impl.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\document_impl.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\engineRegistry.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\junction_impl.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\linkedProperties.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\link_impl.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\LiveNodeWatcher.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\LivePropertyWatcher.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\Marquee.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\model_impl.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\node_impl.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\pad_impl.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\PartLockingHandler.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\part_impl.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\popup_impl.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\propertyScaleCallback.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\property_impl.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\reflection_impl.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\scene_impl.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\spaceActionProcessor.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\spaceOrient3Callback.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\spacePos3Callback.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\spacePosOrientCallback.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\space_impl.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\xyPosCallback.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\xyzPosCallback.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC package\packageManager.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC package\SubjectManager.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC units\numericalFormatter_impl.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC util\AuthenticationDialog.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC util\characterMapDialog.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC util\HttpFileDownloader.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC util\LocaleService.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC util\NetworkProxy.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC util\nodePropertyWatcher.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC util\statGraph.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC validators\baseValidator.h
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC util\crashHandler.cpp
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC ccFoundation\FeatureService.cpp
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC util\statistic.cpp
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    MOC model\transaction.cpp
1>    The system cannot find the path specified.
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3.
1>  Done executing task "CustomBuild" -- FAILED.
1>Done building target "CustomBuild" in project "ccCore.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Done building project "ccCore.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): warning MSB8017: A circular dependency has been detected while executing custom build commands for item "_moc\crashHandler.moc". This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): warning MSB8017: A circular dependency has been detected while executing custom build commands for item "_moc\FeatureService.moc". This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): warning MSB8017: A circular dependency has been detected while executing custom build commands for item "_moc\statistic.moc". This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): warning MSB8017: A circular dependency has been detected while executing custom build commands for item "_moc\transaction.moc". This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3.
1>    4 Warning(s)
1>    1 Error(s)
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.31
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I can't put the full log due to character limit in the body, I am sorry. I read that I need to figure out which build step is causing the error, but I have no idea how to this. Also, why does it say "1>    The system cannot find the path specified." I can find all of the files and open them, why do they fail to open when I build the project. Many thanks, please let me know if I can post any other information if you can help me.

Comment: Have you thoroughly verified that the relative paths are correct from the perspective of make?  (I can tell that they aren't based on the error)

Comment: "The system cannot find the path specified." means, perhaps, that `moc` cannot be found.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer How do I verify the that from the perspective of make? I have not worked much with Visual Studio so I am a bit lost. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing to do with your main problem, but Visual Studio can build the projects of large solutions in parallel. The `1>` just means that the message comes from build process number 1.

Comment: @BoPersson how can I find more information about my main problem which is "cmd.exe" exited with code 3? This does not give me much information.

Comment: @LachP. - Sorry, I don't know. That's why I only left a comment on one detail instead of writing an answer.  :-)

Comment: @BoPersson Still thank you for the help!